# Unable to use space bar in character controller with GetKey to make the player jump

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to coding and Unity3d in general. So trying to learn and figure out how things work and what's what I decided to use some code from an online tutorial made by Jason Weimann on his YT channel to get me started with player movement.
I downloaded the whole project, opened it in Unity (upgraded the project from Unity 2019.3.4f1 to Unity 2020.1.1f1).
Fired up the scene (with few simple environment elements and a player with character controller).
Everything works as it supposed to until I press space to make the player jump.
So I dived into the code, changed `Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)` to `Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E)` and it works... I tried with various other keys and all of them work except for the space bar. I also tried `Input.GetKeyDown` works fine too, but not when the key is specified as Space.
Any idea why this might be happening??
Please see the code below, even though I don't think there's anything wrong with it (since any other key works just fine and I wasn't the one to write it LOL)

***EDIT***
Thanks for all the suggestions so far.
The author of the code was able to get this code to work with `Input.GetKey` even though Unity documentation doesn't mention this key code to work with it (only with `Input.GetKeyDown` and `Input.GetKeyUp`). Script works with any other key code.
I tried using this code in a totally new project and got the same results as before - can't use space to jump, every other key works.
*Could it be something in my Unity3D settings?*

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CharacterMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float _moveSpeed = 10f;
    [SerializeField] private float _jumpSpeed = 0.5f;
    [SerializeField] private float _gravity = 2f;
    
    CharacterController _characterController;
    Vector3 _moveDirection;

    void Awake() => _characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 inputDirection = new Vector3(horizontal, 0, vertical);
        Vector3 transformDirection = transform.TransformDirection(inputDirection);
        
        Vector3 flatMovement = _moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime * transformDirection;

        _moveDirection = new Vector3(flatMovement.x, _moveDirection.y , flatMovement.z);

        if (PlayerJumped)
            _moveDirection.y = _jumpSpeed;
        else if (_characterController.isGrounded)
            _moveDirection.y = 0f;
        else
            _moveDirection.y -= _gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        _characterController.Move(_moveDirection);
    }
//this is the part that does not work when the KeyCode is set to Space, but works with ANY other key.
    private bool PlayerJumped => _characterController.isGrounded && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space); 
}
```

Comment: Don't test in the editor!

Answer (score 1):

Typically you want your property getters to be as simple as possible, usually just getting a value that's been cached rather than calculated since calculating the value every time it's asked for is hard on performance.

Try caching the `Input.GetKey()` command in Update by saving it off in a local variable. Then look at that variable during your FixedUpdate. This has always worked for me and it is considered to be best practice.

As for using Input.GetKey, the Unity documentation tells us that the Space key is detected by Input.GetKeyDown and Input.GetKeyUp, but not Input.GetKey. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html

Comment: Thanks for your input. I totally get what you're talking about (even though my coding knowledge is limited) but why do you think your suggestion would change anything in this case? If I'm able to use any other key than space without caching the command what would caching the command change (apart from any possible performance issues/being more of a good practice than what is used in the code I mentioned in my question)?

Comment: The data behind Input.GetKey is cleared every frame (Update) which does not always sync up with the physics (FixedUpdate). Usually this just means that the button press is not registered until the next frame when asking for it during FixedUpdate. But, what can happen, is that two frames occur before your physics update, this would cause Input.GetKey or, more likely, KeyPressed to not register that the key was ever pressed.

Comment: Wouldn't it be the case for any other key as well? The code works. It might not be perfect, but it works ;) the only issue I have with it is that I doesn't work with the jump key being specified as space. What you're mentioning is actually happening quite a lot when I use ```Input.GetKeyDown``` but not a single time (as far as I can tell) when I use ```Input.GetKey```. BTW not trying to be a smart ass or argue or anything (clearly you know more about this than me) but I just don't get it why it works with any other key than space. I don't think it's the script issue (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: Just to clarify. I really appreciate your input and will definitely look into what you're suggesting. But it just doesn't answer my question and seems unrelated to the issue I'm having - which is being able to use this code to make the player jump with any key I specify but space. If it works with any other key why doesn't it work with the space key?

Comment: In full honesty, I didn't know why space is treated any different from other keys - still really don't. At any rate, the official documentation says that space is only detected by GetKeyDown and GetKeyUp. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/KeyCode.Space.html

Comment: OK, but as mentioned before and in the OP I tried ```Input.GetKeyDown``` too and it just doesn't want to work with the space key. I tried caching ```Input.GetKey``` as you suggested and it doesn't work either... Could it be something in my project input settings or the fact that the project itself was created in a different Unity version? Also the person that created the code was able to execute it with no issues at all, so why can't I? Strange one isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

OK. Apparently this is a known bug that doesn't happen in built game, only in the editor. It incorrectly detects inputs. There's no fix AFAIK.
Don't know if it's Linux only or if other environments are affected too.
Apparently the only way around it is to use a different key or deploy and then test.